# how to use cryptdb in java as a database?

Tags: netbeans

I was trying to use cryptdb as a database in a java program , I am unableto use it. When iI log into mysql , cryptdb is visible as other database . I am using netbeans-7.4 . If I try to connect other database part of mysql it is giving an error.